# How can I construct HTML using NameValuePair in android?

Tags: c#, android, stringbuilder

I'm trying to implement VPOS in my android application. I have C# implementation. I am trying to change according to Android. In C# code;

```
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("mode", strmode); //just one of parameter. 
RedirectAndPOST(this, "url", parameters);
public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);

        page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
    }

    private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        string formID = "PostForm";

        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();

        strForm.AppendFormat("<form id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" action=\"{1}\" method=\"POST\">", formID, url);

        foreach (string key in data)
        {

            strForm.AppendFormat("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\">", key, data[key]);

        }

        strForm.Append("</form>");

        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

        strScript.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");

        strScript.AppendFormat("document.{0}.submit();", formID);

        strScript.Append("</script>");




        return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();


    }
```

In my Java code, first, I created `NameValuePair`, then, I create `preparePOSTMethod` method for construct `HTML`. After, I send `HTTP POST Request`.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", strmode));
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardnumber", cardNumber));
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardexpiredatemonth", cardExpireDateMonth));
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardexpiredateyear", cardExpireDateYear));
 parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardcvv2", CardCvv2));
post = preparePOSTForm("url", parameter);
private static String preparePOSTForm(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)

    {
        String formID = "PostForm";

        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();

        strForm.append(String.format("<form id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" action=\"{1}\" method=\"POST\">", formID, url));

        for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {

            strForm.append(String.format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\">", data.get(i).getName(), data.get(i).getValue()));

        }

        strForm.append("</form>");

        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

        strScript.append("<script language=\"javascript\">");

        strScript.append(String.format("document.{0}.submit();", formID));

        strScript.append("</script>");

        param = strForm.toString() + strScript.toString();
        System.out.println("result:  "+param);
        return strForm.toString() + strScript.toString();
    }
```

However, I cannot construct HTML.

```
Result: <form id="{0}" name="{0}" action="{1}" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"><input type="hidden" name="{0}" value="{1}"></form><script language="javascript">document.{0}.submit();</script>
```

How can I construct `HTML` using Name-Value Pair and StringBuilder or something else?

Comment: `parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", strmode));` Please add more variables and do not use variables as strmode as we then do not know what you use.

Comment: Please format your result. Dont post it on one line. You let us scroll half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 strForm.append(String.format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\">"
      , data.get(i).getName(), data.get(i).getValue()));
```

As you see the parameters are not filled in. You just get that format string unchanged.

Use %s instead of {0} and {1}.

Comment: Thanks for quick response!